# Keep moving an element when one key is pressed jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, keypress

I've been trying to find a solution that allows me to alternate a css property in a div when a single key is kept pressed.

I'm trying to make a character move by using the left and right arrows but I'm not able to make it move when the key is pressed, now it moves just when the right key is pressed and then released.

Here my code:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: //left arrow key
      $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "-150px");
      break;
    case 39: //right arrow key
      $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "-150px");
      $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "0px");
      $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "-150px");
      break;
  }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: //left arrow key
      $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "-150px");
      break;
    case 39: //right arrow key
      $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "0px");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#matteo-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 150px;
}

#matteo-character {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#matteo-walking {
  background: url('http://www.matteoschiatti.it/fancycv/images/matteo-walking.png');
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="matteo-container">
  <div id="matteo-character">
    <div id="matteo-walking"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At this stage, the character keeps moving his legs just if I press and release the right button, is there a way to get the same result when I kept is pressed? I was thinking something like: every X px the left property returns 0px then after X px the left property becomes -150px then again and again but I'm not sure if this is the right way and how to do that because I have also to think about the return of the character.

Here the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/matteous1/uvf2qrds/1/

Comment: have you tried using animation? give it an animation on keydown and remove the animation on keyup

Comment: What you should do is make a CSS animation and apply it while the key is pressed. And remove it only after the key is released.

Comment: And one thing to keep in mind that, your character is not the one which will move, but the background is what will actually move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the fiddle below. I created the same inspired by your work.

https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/uvf2qrds/71/

```
var currentPosition = 0;
var moveVal = 25;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
                currentPosition += moveVal;
        break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
                currentPosition -= moveVal;
        break;
    }
        startMovement();
        setBgPos(currentPosition);
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    endMovement()
});

function startMovement() {
    $('#matteo-walking').addClass('movement');
}

function endMovement() {
    $('#matteo-walking').removeClass('movement');
}

function setBgPos(currentPosition) {
    $('#matteo-container').css('background-position', currentPosition + 'px -300px');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Can I just ask you how I can trigger the animation only by using the left and right keys? Because at the moment the character moves every time I press a random button, not just the arrows. And can I also ask you why I've created the two vars at the beginning and you increase them every time the buttons are pressed?

Comment: Just an update and answer to the question you asked. https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/uvf2qrds/94/

Answer (score 0):

I think you were almost there. I managed to make it work using event listeners for keyup and keydown and by resetting the position. I have based my answer on [this article](https://jsfiddle.net/uvf2qrds/110/)

```
position = 0
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   console.log(event.code)
   handleMovement(event);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   console.log('stopped')
   handleStop(event);
});

function handleMovement(e) {
  if (event.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
    position -= 150
    let newPosition = position + 'px'
    console.log(newPosition)
    $("#matteo-walking").css("left", newPosition);
    $("#matteo-character").css("left", '-50%');
  }
  if (event.code == 'ArrowRight') {
    position -= 150
    let newPosition = position + 'px'
    console.log(newPosition)
    $("#matteo-walking").css("left", newPosition);
    $("#matteo-character").css("left", '50%');
  }
}

function handleStop(e) {
  position = 0
  $("#matteo-walking").css("left", "0px");
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvf2qrds/110/)

Answer (score 0):

I take your code and did some arrangement, its walking now :)

Css (add Class):

```
.step-position
{
   background-position-x : -150px !important;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
 switch (e.which){
    case 37:    //left arrow key
     animateStep();
     break;
    case 39:    //right arrow key
     animateStep();
     break;
   }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
switch (e.which){
case 37:    //left arrow key
    moveStep(false);
    break;
case 39:    //right arrow key
    moveStep(true);
    break;
}
});

function animateStep()
{
  $("#matteo-walking").addClass('step-position');
  setTimeout(function(){$("#matteo-walking").removeClass('step-position');},100);
}

function moveStep(forward)
{
  var step = 30;
  var distance = $("#matteo-character").css("left").replace("px","") * 1;

  if(forward)
  { 
    distance += step;
  }
  else
  {
    distance -= step;
  }

  $("#matteo-character").css("left",distance + "px");
}
```

See [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzoabi/cbax7qjs/)